# CMac calculation in C# using BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, aes, elliptic-curve, ecdh, cmac

I'm trying to implement in c# PACE PIN general Mapping.
At the end of the protocol, we need to calculate tokens by doing this :

**• Derive session keys Kenc and Kmac  from Hmap**

**• Calculate token: TPICC = MAC(Kmac , PKPCD,map), TPCD = MAC(Kmac, PKPICC,map)**

I have already completed the first point, obtaining a key Kenc = SHA1(Kshared || 00000001) and a key Kmac = SHA1(Kshared || 00000002).
Now I have to complete the second point, which consists of calculating the token that will be sent to the chip:

- Calculate token: TPICC = MAC(Kmac , PKPCD,map), TPCD = MAC(Kmac, PKPICC,map)

I implemented a method that I found here: [AES CMAC Calculation C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163493/aes-cmac-calculation-c-sharp)
But when I try to calculate the MAC of a known result, I do not find the same values, the values are not even the same size."

**Here is a log from PlatinumReader, a software that has implemented what I want to implement in my application**:

**PKPCD,map** :

```
04 b6 cb e1 30 44 9b 32 a6 bf e7 86 f2 56 41 a7
c9 c4 a4 99 a6 1b d4 98 69 67 2d f0 3f ba 82 07
26 14 ce d3 2b f2 1d 06 d6 f6 d0 69 6c 80 0e 8c
e4 57 79 94 1a 32 38 b9 28 f0 52 48 af 21 10 ce de
```

***PKPICC,map***

```
04 b5 05 d4 67 8c 5d 7d 1a a8 7b cc c3 d4 24 82
e3 6d df 84 19 5c f9 b0 f4 bb e0 de 69 de d3 04
2c 52 ea b6 b2 64 03 88 4a ff fa 46 01 82 fc bc 
f5 bb 2a aa 64 97 ec e3 59 92 a9 45 1c ef 91 e3 02
```

Key: K_MAC - derived MAC key (K_MAC [PACE])

```
b5 fe b9 48 8f 17 be 03 e5 4c 7d 80 90 7e 8a 1f
```

Key: T_PCD - PCD's calculated authentication token (T_PCD [PACE]) : the result

```
3e 93 48 fc ca 2c 5d dc
```

On my side, I just need the TPCD, then I send it as a request to the chip, and the chip should normally respond with its token which should correspond to the TPICC that I can calculate manually. This ends the process.like this

**APDU: Request sending my token (tcpd) to the chip**

```
00 86 00 00 0c 7c 0a 85 08 3e 93 48 fc ca 2c 5d dc 00
```

**Response : getting the chip token (tpicc) : 8b 9e 28 f9 81 be 50 86**

```
7c 0a 86 08 8b 9e 28 f9 81 be 50 86 90 00
```

And here is my code :

```
byte[] AESCMAC(byte[] key, byte[] data)
 {
     // SubKey generation
     // step 1, AES-128 with key K is applied to an all-zero input block.
     byte[] L = AESEncrypt(key, new byte[8], new byte[16]);

     // step 2, K1 is derived through the following operation:
     byte[] FirstSubkey = Rol(L); //If the most significant bit of L is equal to 0, K1 is the left-shift of L by 1 bit.
     if ((L[0] & 0x80) == 0x80)
         FirstSubkey[15] ^= 0x87; // Otherwise, K1 is the exclusive-OR of const_Rb and the left-shift of L by 1 bit.

     // step 3, K2 is derived through the following operation:
     byte[] SecondSubkey = Rol(FirstSubkey); // If the most significant bit of K1 is equal to 0, K2 is the left-shift of K1 by 1 bit.
     if ((FirstSubkey[0] & 0x80) == 0x80)
         SecondSubkey[15] ^= 0x87; // Otherwise, K2 is the exclusive-OR of const_Rb and the left-shift of K1 by 1 bit.

     // MAC computing
     if (((data.Length != 0) && (data.Length % 16 == 0)) == true)
     {
         // If the size of the input message block is equal to a positive multiple of the block size (namely, 128 bits),
         // the last block shall be exclusive-OR'ed with K1 before processing
         for (int j = 0; j < FirstSubkey.Length; j++)
             data[data.Length - 16 + j] ^= FirstSubkey[j];
     }
     else
     {
         // Otherwise, the last block shall be padded with 10^i
         byte[] padding = new byte[16 - data.Length % 16];
         padding[0] = 0x80;

         data = data.Concat<byte>(padding.AsEnumerable()).ToArray();

         // and exclusive-OR'ed with K2
         for (int j = 0; j < SecondSubkey.Length; j++)
             data[data.Length - 16 + j] ^= SecondSubkey[j];
     }

     // The result of the previous process will be the input of the last encryption.
     byte[] encResult = AESEncrypt(key, new byte[8], data);

     byte[] HashValue = new byte[16];
     Array.Copy(encResult, encResult.Length - HashValue.Length, HashValue, 0, HashValue.Length);

     return HashValue;
 }

 byte[] Rol(byte[] b)
 {
     byte[] r = new byte[b.Length];
     byte carry = 0;

     for (int i = b.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     {
         ushort u = (ushort)(b[i] << 1);
         r[i] = (byte)((u & 0xff) + carry);
         carry = (byte)((u & 0xff00) >> 8);
     }

     return r;
 }

 byte[] AESEncrypt(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] data)
 {
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

         aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
         aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

         using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
         {
             cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
             cs.FlushFinalBlock();

             return ms.ToArray();
         }
     }
 }
```

And i call the function here :

```
byte[] tipcc = AESCMAC(StringToByteArray("b5feb9488f17be03e54c7d80907e8a1f"), StringToByteArray("b6cbe130449b32a6bfe786f25641a7c9c4a499a61bd49869672df03fba820726"));

addLogMsg("MAC : " + byteToHexStr(tipcc));
```

and the transformation methods are :

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
 {
     return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                      .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                      .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                      .ToArray();
 }
```

And :

```
public string byteToHexStr(byte[] bytes)
 {
     string returnStr = "";
     if (bytes != null)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
         {
             returnStr += bytes[i].ToString("X2");
         }
     }
     return returnStr;
 }
```

Comment: Have you determined `PKPCD,map` and `PKPICC,map`? What should `b6cbe130449b32a6bfe786f25641a7c9c4a499a61bd49869672df03fba820726` be? This is too short for `PKPCD,map` or `PKPICC,map`! And why don't you use BC's CMAC?

Comment: @Topaco
Yes ! I have edited the question and put the correct PKCD,map.
I'm using AES-128.
These data come from the PlatinumReader where the protocol is already well implemented. I'm trying to reproduce the same on my application, using the process used in the log file. Is there a way I can share the entire log file with you?

Comment: Your test data is still incomplete! You have now supplied test data for `Kmac` and `PKPCD,map`. This can be used to determine the authentication token `TPICC=MAC(Kmac , PKPCD,map)`. However, you have not posted test data for the `TPICC` token, but for the `TPCD` token, which means that it is not possible to check the `TPICC` token. Therefore, post test data for the `TPICC` token. If you also want to verify the `TPCD=MAC(Kmac, PKPICC,map)` token, you must also post test data for `PKPICC,map`.

Comment: This data can all be determined from the PlatinumReader log.

Comment: I added all two tokens and the token exchange request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication token for *id-PACE-ECDH-GM-AES-CBC-CMAC-128* (see PlatinumReader log) is a CMAC (see [Doc 9303](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf), *p. 15*), which can be easily determined with BouncyCastle:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Macs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using System;
...
var k_mac_hex = "b5feb9488f17be03e54c7d80907e8a1f";
var prefix_hex = "7f494f060a04007f000702020402028641";
var pk_picc_map = "04b505d4678c5d7d1aa87bccc3d42482e36ddf84195cf9b0f4bbe0de69ded3042c52eab6b26403884afffa460182fcbcf5bb2aaa6497ece35992a9451cef91e302"; // change

var k_mac = Convert.FromHexString(k_mac_hex);
var cmac_t_pcd = Convert.FromHexString(prefix_hex + pk_picc_map);

var macBlock = new CMac(new AesEngine());
macBlock.Init(new KeyParameter(k_mac));
macBlock.BlockUpdate(cmac_t_pcd, 0, cmac_t_pcd.Length);
var t_pcd = new byte[16];
macBlock.DoFinal(t_pcd, 0);

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(t_pcd[..8]).ToLower()); // 3e9348fcca2c5ddc
```

This returns the expected value for the `T_PCD` authentication token 0x3e9348fcca2c5ddc.

The prefix `prefix_hex` can be taken from the document [Doc 9303](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf), *p. App G-8/G-9* and corresponds together with the public key to an ASN.1 encoding of OID and key, see [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#f0lPBgoEAH8ABwICBAIChkEEtQXUZ4xdfRqoe8zD1CSC423fhBlc-bD0u-Dead7TBCxS6rayZAOISv_6RgGC_Lz1uyqqZJfs41mSqUUc75HjAg).

Comment: thanks it works !
I'm posting a new question about the process after exchanging tokens.
Its about secure messaging requests, should i use the token that i got from the chip to calcultate something ?

Comment: @Bouls - You actually only need to determine `t_picc` analogous to the algorithm posted in my answer, which results in `0x8b9e28f981be5086` (s. online here https://dotnetfiddle.net/viRQ7p) and, according to your posted data, is equal to the authentication token sent in the response, which indicates successful authentication. If anything is unclear, please post a new question with all the details and test data needed to answer it.

Comment: Yes I did, I used the method from your response and I am able to receive the t_picc token, but my question is about the next steps in the process. Do I need to calculate something in each APDU request? How do I use this received token?

Comment: @Bouls - I don't have any documentation on the process beyond PACE authentication, so I can't help from here. If you have documentation, you should post a link to it in your new question.

Comment: I have posted a link in my new question where they explain it I didn't understand how it really works! (see (https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf) page 91 : D.4 SECURE MESSAGING)